# AngularJS, difference between ng-class and class with angular expression?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

What is the difference between the following two code snippets,

Code 1:

```
<div class={{getClass()}}/>
```

Code 2:

```
<div ng-class=getClass()/>
```

Comment: I believe `ng-class` will be evaluated at the end of every `digest`, where as `{{ getClass() }}` is evaluated once.

Comment: `ng-class` is usually used to evaluate expressions and apply class(es) based on expressions

Comment: @Pete not really, since it's in an angular expression it will get evaluated with any scope change

Comment: @charlietfl Good point. Just ran a test and it does get evaluated.

Answer (score 7):

With the first example before angular loads your class will literally be "{{getClass()}}". While in the second example the div won't have a class until angular runs its first digest.

There might be some minor differences with when they are recalculated but Angular will keep both up to date. I've run into issues before using the first method with Animation as ng-class has some hooks into animation.

Comment: they are not really the same when you get into using conditionals in `ng-class`. Outcome of OP example will result in same but `ng-class` has more specific use than `class` also

Comment: I mean that his two example are pretty much the same. Not ng-class and class="{{}}"

Comment: right but in a case like `class="form-group"   ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.course.subtitle.$invalid && isSubmitted}"` they are not anywhere near the same