# AngularJS - Live update button style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I'm trying to make a `a-tag` designer in `AngularJS`, my only problem is that the `class` and `style` of the `a-tag` doesn't update.

The code I have so far is this: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/michaeltot/pen/reVQPY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because in this block of code;

```
<!-- Button example -->
<div class="item">
    <h4>Example</h4>
    <a style="{{botton.css.style}}" class="{{botton.css.class}}">
        <i class="{{botton.css.icon}}"></i> {{ button.text }}
    </a>
</div>
```

You have called it `botton` instead of `button` ?

Edit: Yes that is why.

Answer (score 1):

you must use ng-style and ng-class instead style and class for binding
and dont use {{}} on value

```
ng-class="button.css.class"
```

and you have typo in binding syntax replace "botton" with "button"

```
<div class="item">
    <h4>Example</h4>
    <a ng-style="botton.css.style" ng-class="button.css.class">
    <i ng-class="button.css.icon"></i> {{ button.text }}
</a>
```

it should works!

Comment: What difference does it make to use `ng-class="button.css.style"` instead of `class="{{button.css.style}}"`?

Comment: they are very similar but in ng-class you can use conditions -  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578501/angularjs-difference-between-ng-class-and-class-with-angular-expression)